# Logging into docker

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I am unable to push to dockerhub and I think it is because of an authentication problem.

I am following the instructions in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html

I have logged into docker (Step 9a).  I am pretty sure I am logged in because I get this output:

```
WARNING: login credentials saved in /home/fedora/.docker/config.json
Login Succeeded
```

However, when I try to verify my login (Step 9b), I do not see any Username `docker info | grep Username` yields nothing.

Then when I skip ahead to step 9c, it does not work because:

```
f4e8ebedd614: Preparing 
unauthorized: access to the requested resource is not authorized
```

suggesting I was not really logged in.

To be sure, I logged out and relogged in using bogus credentials.  In that case, I get `Error response from daemon: Wrong login/password, please try again`

Then I logged out and relogged in again using the correct credentials, and steps 9b and 9c continue to not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my docker issue.  There were 2 separate issues that kept me from being able to push.

1. I had not created a docker repository.  I was following the instructions on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html.  It told me to create a docker account, so I created a docker account.  It did not tell me to create a docker repository, so I did not create one.  It is now obvious that you have to create a docker repository.  I have made my docker repository public and added my user as a collaborator (I am not sure that was necessary).  I logged out and relogged in (also not sure if that was necessary).
2. I needed to edit my ~/.docker/config file as discussed here https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-push-not-working-in-1-8-1-not-logged-in/2894/17.  This command should do the trick `sed -i "s#docker.io#https://index.docker.io/v1/# ~/.docker/config`.  I have created a bug report https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/21028 about this.